Implement chats in a MAUI app with ChatGPT valid for a session
In my .NET 8 MAUI app, I like to implement a chat with different ChatGPT users about different topics. I saw there are a few NuGet packages to interact with ChatGPT but in particular I saw OpenAI-DotNet that seems quite complete.
The GitHub repo has examples but none of them explains how to create more messages in the same chat with the same conversationId. I like to get a json to manage the answer from ChatGpt better. For example:
using var api = new OpenAIClient();

var messages = new List<Message>
{
    new Message(Role.System, "You are a helpful assistant designed to output JSON."),
    new Message(Role.User, "Who won the world series in 2020?"),
};

var chatRequest = new ChatRequest(messages, Model.GPT4o, 
                                  responseFormat: ChatResponseFormat.Json);

var response = await api.ChatEndpoint.GetCompletionAsync(chatRequest);

foreach (var choice in response.Choices)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"[{choice.Index}] {choice.Message.Role}: {choice} " + 
                      $"| Finish Reason: {choice.FinishReason}");
}

response.GetUsage();

In this example, there is no interaction with a user. chatRequest doesn't contain a conversationId and I can't find how to pass this value if I want to add a new message from the user.
Also, in the app, the user can leave the chat page and then open it later but the conversation should continue.
If it is easy, I'm OK to use OpenAI official package.

Pretty sure the expected usage is just to do messages.append(new Message(...)) and then do GetCompletionAsync again.  Why do you need a conversationid?
